# editor which performs well searching text through a huge codebase

Tags: visual-studio-code, full-text-search, sublimetext3, atom-editor

I have a huge text codebase on Windows and I am facing the problem of searching arbitrary words across the whole project.

Seemingly, no IDE scores good performances when doing so. What I am looking for is a free editor that:

- **searches full text** through the folder and subfolder in an acceptable time (ideally less than 10 seconds for 10M lines of code).
- Almost surely, the previous feature entails in using an index. So I'd like such **index to be automatically in sync with file changes. Or** at least to have the option to **rebuild it on demand incrementally** (not a full rebuild)
- shows the search results in context (with snippets of the surroundng code around, pretty much like Sublime does).
- ideally, be able to search for **regex patterns**
- ...and even, to search for regex through *multiline* strings.

I do not need it to be code-aware, but if it were able to understand PL/SQL it would be my dream editor.

So far my first choice was Sublime, which is an incredibly responsive editor.
Sublime 3 shipped with an internal index, but unfortunately for me, indexes just the symbols, not the full text.
The built-in brute force search cannot use that index and takes around 40 mins to return the results.

I tried several **Sublime extensions** which plug into external indexing tools (CodeSearch, Platinum Searcher, Whoosh). But all failed to provide automated or incremental index rebuild, or when they did offer those features, the indexing itself took so much memory that the entire app became unresponsive forever, or the plugin host broke down.

I also tried similar approaches with **Atom** and **Visual Studio Code**, but I believe that the editors and their plugins weren't written for such an insanely large codebase as I have at hands.

The only editor that performed well was Eclipse with the [InstaSearch](https://github.com/ajermakovics/eclipse-instasearch) plugin.
However the speed that I gain in the search is lost in ordinary usage: opening a file, scrolling through its content, etc (not to mention that the plugin uses Lucene's syntax, not regex).
(It feels like if one is not using Java related technologies, there is no real benefit in using Eclipse which really offsets the heaviness of operating with it)

Comment: Do you need it integrated into your IDE? Could the windows equivalent of grep be sufficient?

Comment: not well integrated, but I do need a way to quickly open the file when "clicking" the search results. And `grep` is not fast enough. I believe only indexes can solve this...